# How to make centered resizable view based on content

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I want to create a view inside of it there are 3 labels that have dynamic height.
I want the Labels to appear in the center of the text is small and got bigger when the text gets bigger Priority for the last label (Description).

**What I am Getting**

[image]

**Expected Result**

**1- Small description**

[image]

**2- Big description**

[image]

**Also if the description is very long the height of the labels should not exceed the boundaries of the image the top and bottom constraints should**

Any fix for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `UIStackView` for your needs.

Just follow the steps listed below to get this result:

1. Add `UIImageView` and config constraints: leading, top, bottom, and width (constant or proportional).
2. Add `UILabels` (and don`t forget to set number of lines to 0)
   [image]
3. Select labels and add them to Stack View. Set `Fill` value in `Alignment` and `Distribution` fields.
   [image]
4. Add `leading` and `trailing` constraints to Stack View
   [image]
5. Add vertical centering constraints to Stack View
   [image]

**Updated after editings in original question - "if the description is very long the height of the labels should not exceed the boundaries of the image the top and bottom constraints should"**

6. Select Stack view and Image view and add Top and Bottom Edges constraints.
   [image]
7. Select just added Top Edge constraint and change `Relation` in `Attributes Inspector` to `Greater Than or Equal`. After this select Bottom Edge constraint and change `Relation` to `Less Than or Equal`.
8. Select the first two labels and set in `Size Inspector` Vertical `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to 751.
   [image]

   That`s all

   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Very helpful But I forgot to mention that the bottom of the description should not be taller than the image @ and the top of the top label should at max the top of the image

Comment: @JhonnyTawk oh, okay - give me couple minutes to edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very helpful and it's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You can simply manage this using stack.
if you see the image you can see there are three stacks. If you configure them correctly you can simply achieve the behaviour you want.
 [view document outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB5OP.png)

in ContainerStack from image you need to set Alignment as **fill** and distribution **fill equally** (you can change this if you want to align the text part and image part differently) you can also give spacing as you want

in LabelHorizondalContainer Stack you need set this as Alignment **Center** and distribution as fill

in LabelVerticalContainer Stack you need to set as Alignment and distribution as **fill**

This should do the trick As far as I know

[small description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP6Hc.png)

[Bigger description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfhzX.png)

By the way you need to set the vertical compression resistants for the label accordingly to make sure which label should be trunked when you have bigger description which will fill the view.